# How to perform a segue upon clicking a UIViewTableCell?

Tags: ios, swift

how do I perform a segue when I click a UITableViewCell, I have a segue already in the storyboard going from the UITableView to the next View Controller? I've been told to use the 'didSelectRowAt' functionality but can't seem to get it to work!

The view controller I'm trying to access is called "VendorHome" and the controller it comes from is called "Home Controller" also the UITableView, UITableCellView and content UIView are classless if that helps.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeCellToVendorPage", sender: self)
}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DataCellLabels.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = HomeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath)
    as! HomeCell
    cell.UsernameLabel.text = DataCellLabels[indexPath.row].Title
    cell.DistanceLabel.text = DataCellLabels[indexPath.row].Distance
    cell.StarRatingLabel.text = DataCellLabels[indexPath.row].Rating
    cell.AvailabilityLabel.text = DataCellLabels[indexPath.row].Avaliability
    

    return cell
}

let db = Firestore.firestore()

var DataCellLabels: [CellLabel] = []

@IBOutlet weak var HomeTableView: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    HomeTableView.dataSource = self
    
    
    HomeTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HomeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell")
    
    LoadHomeCells()
}

func LoadHomeCells() {
    DataCellLabels = []
    
    db.collection("users").getDocuments { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
        if let e = error {
            print ("Error \(e)")
        } else {
            if let snapshotDocuments = QuerySnapshot?.documents {
                for doc in snapshotDocuments {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    if let CellTitle = data["Username"] as? String , let CellDistance = data["Distance"] as? String, let CellRating = data["Rating"] as? String, let CellAvaliability = data["Avaliability"] as? String {
                        let NewCell = CellLabel(Title: CellTitle, Distance: CellDistance, Rating: CellRating ,Avaliability: CellAvaliability)
                        self.DataCellLabels.append(NewCell)
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.HomeTableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're only setting the `dataSource`, you also need to set the table view `delegate`.

```
HomeTableView.delegate = self
```

`didSelectRowAtIndex` is a UITableViewDelegate method, not a datasource one

Comment: You're a beast, been up hours trying to fix that :D

Comment: please accept this answer if it helped! thanks 

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to add delegate:

```
HomeTableView.delegate = self
```